# Should I put my diplomas and specializations under education or relevant skills and courses in my CV when applying to a Mphil?

Tags: graduate-admissions, cv

Typically I would put them under the education section of my CV for my applications in the Dominican Republic, but I'm not sure if this should be the case for my graduate application.

PS: The diploma was a three month course called a "diplomado" in Spanish. The specializations are essentially the first year of a graduate course.

Comment: does it really matter all that much where you put it as long as you do put it somewhere?

Comment: Sursula, I think it matters a lot, especially with a longer CV. Education usually is on the first page, while skills are (at least in y experience), at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Education because

(1) 'relevant skills' is not always a heading in CVs, while 'education' is.

(2) skills are not the papers/degrees collected. What kind of skill is BSc (or in your case diplomado) in Spanish? With skills you would probably list your speaking/writing/reading/listening skills in Spanish plus any additional skills the education gave you.